# Java regular expression for masked alphanumeric codes

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I need a help to use or build a regular expression to mask alphanumeric with `*`.

I tried it with this expression, but it doesn't work correctly when it has zeros in the middle of the string:

```
(?<=[^0].{3})\w+(?=\w{4})
```

Live samples:
https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyf47wp3r

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| 0001113033AA55608981 | 0001113*********8981 |
| 23456237472347823923 | 2345************3923 |
| 00000000090000000000 | 0000000009000***0000 |
| 09008000800060050000 | 09008***********0000 |
| AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEE | AAAA************EEEE |
| 0000BBBBCCCCDDDDEEEE | 0000BBBB********EEEE |

The rules are:

1. The first 4 that are not zeros, and the last 4 a must be displayed.
2. Leading zeros are ignored, but not removed or replaced.

Comment: don't just drop your assignment here. what specific issues do you have?

Comment: What do you mean with “it doesn't work correctly”? The output fulfills the rules you have posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture initial zeros and 3 alhpanumeric chars right after them in one group, the middle part into a second group, and then the last 4 alphanumeric chars into a third group, then only replace each char in the second group.

Here is an example (Java 11 compliant):

```java
String text = "0001113033AA55608981";
Matcher mr = Pattern.compile("^(0*\\w{4})(.*)(\\w{4})$").matcher(text);
text = mr.replaceFirst(m -> m.group(1) + "*".repeat(m.group(2).length()) + m.group(3));
System.out.println(text); // => 0001113**********8981
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/gTjIiN).

The regex matches

- `^`  - start of string
- `(0*\w{4})` - Group 1: zero or more `0` chars and then any four alphnumeric/underscore chars
- `(.*)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars (replace with `\w*` if you only allow "word" chars)
- `(\w{4})` - Group 3: four "word" chars
- `$` - end of string.

Java 8 compliant version:

```java
String text = "0001113033AA55608981";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^(0*\\w{4})(.*)(\\w{4})$").matcher(text);
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(result, m.group(1) + String.join("", Collections.nCopies(m.group(2).length(), "*")) + m.group(3));
}
m.appendTail(result);
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

See the [Java code demo online](https://ideone.com/yuCt5j).

But you may just use

```java
String text = "0001113033AA55608981";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^(0*\\w{4})(.*)(\\w{4})$").matcher(text);
String result = "";
if (m.matches()) {
    result = m.group(1) + String.join("", Collections.nCopies(m.group(2).length(), "*")) + m.group(3);
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: how is the version compatible with Java 8?

Comment: A more efficient Java 8 version would use `String result; StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(text.length()); if(m.find()) { char[] tmp = new char[m.end(2) - m.start(2)]; Arrays.fill(tmp, '*'); result = sb.append(text, 0, m.end(1)) .append(tmp).append(text, m.start(3), text.length()).toString(); } else result = text;`

Answer (score 2):

No calls to the `replace` function. Only a "pure " [regex](https://regex101.com/r/i7duM4/9).

```
(?:^(0*[^0].{3})|\G).(?=.{4,}$)
```

The regex can be broken down as follows.

```
(?:              group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------
  ^                the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------
  (                group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------
    0*              '0' (0 or more times (matching
                    the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------
    [^0]             any character except '0'
----------------------------------------------------------
    .{3}             any character except \n (3 times)
----------------------------------------------------------
  )                end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------
 |                OR
----------------------------------------------------------
  \G               where the last m//g left off
----------------------------------------------------------
)                end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------
.                any character except \n
----------------------------------------------------------
(?=              look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------
  .{4,}            any character except \n (at least 4
                   times (matching the most amount
                   possible))
----------------------------------------------------------
  $                before an optional \n, and the end of a
                   "line"
----------------------------------------------------------
)                end of look-ahead
```

See a Java [demo](https://rextester.com/KHNSJ28271).

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Rextester {
  public static void main(String[] asd){
    final String rx = "(?:^(0*[^0].{3})|\\G).(?=.{4,}$)";
    final String text = "0001113033AA55608981\n"
                      + "23456237472347823923\n"
                      + "00000000090000000000\n"
                      + "09008000800060050000\n"
                      + "AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEE\n"
                      + "0000BBBBCCCCDDDDEEEE\n"
                      + "00000000000000000000";
    final String subs = "$1*";
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(rx, Pattern.MULTILINE);
    final Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    final String res = m.replaceAll(subs);
    System.out.println(res);
  }  
}
```

Output.

```
0001113*********8981
2345************3923
0000000009000***0000
09008***********0000
AAAA************EEEE
0000BBBB********EEEE
00000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java you could use a finite quantifier in a lookbehind assertion.

```
(?<=^0{0,100}[^\W0]\w{3,100})\w(?=\w{4,}$)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert that to the left is

  - `^0{0,100}` Match 0-100 zero's from the start of the string (the 100 is arbitrary)
  - `[^\W0]` Match a word character other than a zero
  - `\w{3,100}` Match 3-100 word characters (where the 100 is again arbitrary)
- `)` Close the lookbehind
- `\w` Match a single word character
- `(?=\w{4,}$)` Positive lookahead, assert 4 or more word characters to the end of the string

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/miP3wp) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/02Ni9J/1)

```
String[] strings = {
    "0001113033AA55608981",
    "23456237472347823923",
    "00000000090000000000",
    "09008000800060050000",
    "AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEE",
    "0000BBBBCCCCDDDDEEEE"
};

for (String s : strings) {
    String regex = "(?<=^0{0,100}[^\\W0]\\w{3,100})\\w(?=\\w{4,}$)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    System.out.println(m.replaceAll("*"));
}
```

Output

```
0001113*********8981
2345************3923
0000000009000***0000
09008***********0000
AAAA************EEEE
0000BBBB********EEEE
```

Answer (score -1):

A good regex would be `(?<=[^0]\w{3}\w*)\w(?=\w{4})`.

Unfortunately, in Java you can't use unbounded lookbehinds, but you can use

```
(?<=[^0]\w{3,14})\w(?=\w{4})
```

if you know that your string is at most 20 characters long (14 = 20 minus the first character, minus the one you're matching, minus the last 4 ones).

See a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/hvMU2x/1).

Clearly this value can be computed dynamically, e.g.:

```java
for (String text : Arrays.asList("0001113033AA55608981",
                                 "23456237472347823923",
                                 "00000000090000000000",
                                 "09008000800060050000",
                                 "AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEE",
                                 "0000BBBBCCCCDDDDEEEE")) {
    System.out.println(text.replaceAll("(?<=[^0]\\w{3," + (text.length()-6) + "})\\w(?=\\w{4})", "*"));
}
```

([demo](https://ideone.com/mXDu4A))